# Which is better support when you have high range carry like Tristana or Caitlyn?

Tags: league-of-legends

So I've been wondering which support is best for high range carry? Since i love to play as a support i'm still confuse which one is best for those two. I always played Janna, which gives lots of AD just by her shield, but some people rather get Taric or Alli, like we saw on ggChronicle tournament games.

Comment: Really bad question that is completely subjective.  I would say ashe is best support champ for all the slows, a free decent range CV, and the best initiation in the game.

Comment: This question is vague, voting to close.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on how the carry plays. If they're playing cautiously, you might as well just run Soraka. If they're willing to play aggressively, champions like Taric, Ali, or Leona are good picks.

Janna does really well in both active and passive lanes, depending on whether or not you can cast your shield quickly enough to mitigate harass from the other team.

Answer (score 2):

With a tristana and alistar lane there is a lot of kill potential at level 2 because of the potential burst that they have.

Another useful support for them is Nunu. Blood boil is very very strong on cait and tristana.

Answer (score 2):

I would say Janna for her passive and her shield. But let's take a look:

First thing first. you can have LOT's of champions as support, so i will focus on those 3 you said in your post:

**[Janna](http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Janna_the_Storm%27s_Fury)**

> ***Combos:***
>
> - Tailwind(passive): +3% movement speed
> - Zephyr: Slow the target, so the ad carry can keep attacking for more    time without so much walk.
> - Howling Gale: Knocking the opponent, and making it easy to the ad    carry follow and kill him.
> - Eye Of The Storm: The main reason.
>
> Shield Strength: 80 / 120 / 160 / 200 / 240 (+0.9 per ability power)
>
> Attack Damage Bonus: 14 / 23 / 32 / 41 / 50
>
> ***Conclusion:***
>
> Great for hold the opponent in the same place while bursting the ally
>   attack.

**[Taric](http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Taric_the_Gem_Knight)**

> ***Combos:***
>
> - Imbue: Heal, giving a good survivability in lane.
> - Shatter: Great for the armor reduction.
>
> Armor Reduction: 10 / 15 / 20 / 25 / 30
>
> - Dazzle: 1.5 second stun. great for burst.
>
> ***Conclusion:***
>
> Keep a good survivability in the lane. Can tank some minions more then
>   others supports. good burster.

**[Alistar](http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Alistar_the_Minotaur)**

> ***Combos:***
>
> - Pulverize: Not much to talk besides this: "knocking them up for 1    second, additionally stunning them upon landing for 0.5 seconds.".
> - Headbutt: Pulverize + Headbutt is a fatal combo in early, mid and    some times end game.
> - Triumphant Roar: Heal, giving a good survivability in lane.
>
> ***Conclusion:***
>
> Best CC support ever. good when you need lock the opponent.

As you can see. All 3 are great supports, but as I said in the beginner of my answer, I Take Janna for her shield and passive. But this is more a question about who like what, ask your AD Carry what he want as support.

Comment: I have to say, this is a great answer. +1, 2 if i could.

Comment: @JulianG. Thank you for the compliment =) I'm really glad to help xD

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what you want to accomplish.

If your team needs a psuedo-tank, Alistar is your man. If you're going for early kills, Taric and Sona are your best bets. If you're looking for best late-game support, Janna is yours, and if you're looking to sustain and freefarm, Soraka is the one.

Let me break it down to explain the MAJOR reasons. I could sit here and type out how every ability makes the character good/useful, but I'm just going to highlight the main aspects.

ALISTAR - His ult lets him initiate, and he's the only support quite capable of doing it. If your team lacks a tank, Alistar can fulfill this role for a team.

TARIC - huge burst potential early game, the shatter can put enemy champions at extremely low armor, letting your AD practically hit for true damage.

SONA - great harass in lane, and an AoE stun ult makes her useful for level 6 burst ganks

SORAKA - great for champions that rely on mana for harass or farm. If you're corki, MF or Kog'maw, you'll love having a Soraka to infuse you.

JANNA - Best for last. Probably the most impacting support champion lategame. Janna comes equipped with 3 CC's and a shield, she's the single most powerful champion in the game when it comes to peeling off your carry. With that being said, she's also the hardest to master. It's easy to see the difference between a good Janna and a mediocre janna. She struggles in lane slightly more than the others because she has no heal, this requires you to PRE-SHIELD damage! AKA you must have fast reaction and shield before your AD carry takes hits. It takes some getting used to, but very useful if done correctly.

Let me know if you have any other questions :)

Comment: Uhh, to initiate you really just need to get someone out of position and CC them.  It kinda forces a fight to break out if the other team wants the champ alive or they lose the champ and are at a disadvantage.  So really, any support with such a initiation can do this.  Janna can flash-ult to separate the team, Taric can dazzle a high priority target that can be chain CC'ed by his team, Leona, similar to Alistar also can become tanky, get in the middle of a target and ult.

Answer (score 0):

This question is way too much of a discussion, as when played right, every single support is viable, and there are no "best".  Only best given certain team comps vs team comps matchups.  This is of course only theory crafting.  Additionally, best varies in which stage of the game it is.

As such, for utility throughout the game of movement speed global passive, a monster shield that gives AD, an AOE knockup and knockback that heals.  I will say Janna is better support for all ADs but that of course isn't the case.  ADs that benefit from attack speed more, like Kogmaw and Vayne don't benefit as much from Janna since a lot of their damage comes from their W, so Nunu works great for them, as would warwick and gangplank.  If you never seen any of these champs used as support roles, play some blind pick normal games...

Answer (score -1):

Taric and Ali go great with Caitlyn as she can lay a Snap Trap under the stunned champ allowing for a lot of free shots.